# Why is the quadrupole tensor for a hollow sphere a diagonal matrix?

Tags: electrostatics, multipole-expansion

I have determined a quadrupole tensor for a hollow sphere with radius $R$ and charge density $\rho(\theta)$. The tensor has the following form:$$Q=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}Q_{11} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & Q_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 Q_{11}\end{array}\right)$$ Why are only the diagonal elements non-zero? I have found this through calculation, but could I have recognized this directly?

Comment: *I have found this through calculation.* What formula did you use to calculate it? Did you consider what effect the symmetries of the sphere have on the calculation?

Comment: $$Q_{i j}=Q_{j i}=\int \rho\left(\vec{r}^{\prime}\right)\left[3 r_{i}^{\prime} r_{j}^{\prime}-\delta_{i j}\left|\vec{r}^{\prime}\right|^{2}\right] d^{3} \vec{r}^{\prime} \\
\sum \limits_{i=1}^{3} Q_{i i}=0 \\$$ No I don't know how to utilize the symmetry of the sphere. I calculated every entry

Answer (score 0):

The charge density depends on $ \frac{z}{r} = \cos \theta$ only. Integrals over linear factors $\frac{x}{r} = \sin \theta \cos \phi$ and $\frac{y}{r} = \sin \theta \sin \phi$ are zero by periodicity, the same over products by periodicity of $\sin \phi \cos \phi$, only the squares on the diagonal yield constants with the same weight from $\int_0^\pi \sin\theta \rho(\theta) d \theta$